# Thread 1: signal SIGABRT in main.m file

Tags: objective-c, xcode, sigabrt

I need some help in Xcode. I am getting the error Thread 1: SIGABRT and it is pointing to the main.m file. I set up the exception breakpoint and it still stops in the main.m file.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

#import "AppDelegate.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

That is the code that I have in my main.m file. Can someone please help me with this error.

The full error is:

```
2013-09-07 23:41:05.440 save the jewel 5[86090:c07] -[game pause:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x845ece0
2013-09-07 23:41:09.460 save the jewel 5[86090:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[game pause:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x845ece0'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1693012 0x13a0e7e 0x171e4bd 0x1682bbc 0x168294e 0x13b4705 0x2e82c0 0x2e8258 0x3a9021 0x3a957f 0x3a86e8 0x317cef 0x317f02 0x2f5d4a 0x2e7698 0x26f5df9 0x26f5ad0 0x1608bf5 0x1608962 0x1639bb6 0x1638f44 0x1638e1b 0x26f47e3 0x26f4668 0x2e4ffc 0x23c2 0x22f5)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

In my game.m file I have:

```
-(void)pauseLayer:(CALayer*)layer{
    CFTimeInterval pausedTime = [layer convertTime:CACurrentMediaTime() fromLayer:nil];
    layer.speed = 0.0;
    layer.timeOffset = pausedTime;
}

-(void)resumeLayer:(CALayer*)layer{
    CFTimeInterval pausedTime = [layer timeOffset];
    layer.speed = 1.0;
    layer.timeOffset = 0.0;
    layer.beginTime = 0.0;
    CFTimeInterval timeSincePause = [layer convertTime:CACurrentMediaTime() fromLayer:nil] - pausedTime;
    layer.beginTime = timeSincePause;
}


- (IBAction)pause:(id)sender {
    [self pauseLayer:self.view.layer];

}

- (IBAction)resume:(id)sender {
    [self resumeLayer:self.view.layer];
}
```

In my game.h file I have:

```
- (IBAction)pause:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)resume:(id)sender;


-(void)pauseLayer:(CALayer*)layer;
-(void)resumeLayer:(CALayer*)layer;
```

I need some help.

Comment: You can get more details by adding a breakpoint for all exceptions.  It will then reveal what line of your code is causing the crash.

Comment: what do you mean a breakpoint for all exceptions

Comment: My breakpoint is already for all exceptions

Comment: That's strange, is there any console output?

Comment: I just updated my post with the console output

Comment: The main function wouldn't be the problem. " -[game pause:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x845ece0" is the culprit.  Where do you implement the `pause:` method?

Comment: But I don't see that code( -[game pause:]:)

Comment: Maudicus so what should i do?

Comment: Do you have a `game` class? Does that have a `pause:` method? Please show the *implementation* of the method and how you *call* the method.

Comment: I made an edit and it shows the method

Comment: Martin can you help me with this

Comment: Martin are you there????

Answer (score 2):

`-[game pause:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x845ece0`

This means that you have an instance of the `game` class (which, btw, that class should be `Game`, not `game`, classes are capitalized) and something is calling the method `pause:` on that class, but there is no `pause:` method.

Given that the class is called `Game` (fixed) and pausing seems like a reasonable thing to do to a game, it is unlikely that this is an over-release problem.  `pause:` seems like it is something that you might have a button hooked up to in interface builder.

Did you, perchance, rename the `pause:` method to something else (`pauseGame:`?) and not fix the connection in IB?

---

And that `pause:` implementation is inside the `@implementation Game` scope?  If so, trying cleaning the project and rebuilding as there may be a dependency issue.  If not, then that is your problem.

If the build from clean thing doesn't work, then there is some detail missing.   Since building from clean didn't work, you'll have to post more details.  Show the declaration of the class, at least.

Comment: @LoverofApple This isn't a chat system, nor are any of us who are answering this getting paid for it.... you'll have to be patient.  I did update the answer;  read the last paragraph.

Comment: @LoverofApple You haven't added any additional details to the question.  Add the class declaration and more of the implementation details.  Maybe a screenshot of how the button is configured in IB.

Comment: WHat do you mean by the class declaration??

Comment: @LoverofApple Post the class implementation.  The `@implementation` that contains the `pause:` method.